# Show duplicates from SQL join

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

**Table 1- Job**

```
JobID
JobCustomerID
JobAddressID
```

**Table 2- Addresses**

```
AddressID
AStreetAddress
```

**Table 3- Customer**

```
CustomerID
CustomerName
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Jobs] 
LEFT JOIN [Addresses] ON [Jobs].JobAddressID = dbo.Addresses.AddressID  
LEFT JOIN [Customers] ON [Jobs].JobCustomerID = [Customers].CustomerID
GROUP BY AStreetAddress
HAVING (COUNT(AStreetAddress) > 1)
```

I am trying to find the jobs with duplicated addresses.

Error

> Column Jobs.JobID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: how would that be possible? ( assuming `dbo.Addresses.AddressID` is the primary key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With group by you can use in select only columns that are in group by or aggregate functions:

```
SELECT AStreetAddress
FROM [Jobs] 
LEFT JOIN [Addresses] ON [Jobs].JobAddressID = dbo.Addresses.AddressID  
LEFT JOIN [Customers] ON [Jobs].JobCustomerID = [Customers].CustomerID
GROUP BY AStreetAddress
HAVING (COUNT(AStreetAddress) > 1)
```

You need something like this:

```
SELECT [Jobs].ID
FROM [Jobs] 
LEFT JOIN [Addresses] ON [Jobs].JobAddressID = dbo.Addresses.AddressID  
LEFT JOIN [Customers] ON [Jobs].JobCustomerID = [Customers].CustomerID
GROUP BY [Jobs].ID
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked great. I knew it had to do with the data I was selecting but was looking toward jobid.

Comment: @DanielMaher i looked through my old answers and found this one, can you accept it or i should improve it?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Jobs] 

  left JOIN [Addresses] ON [Jobs].JobAddressID = dbo.Addresses.AddressID  
  left JOIN [Customers] ON [Jobs].JobCustomerID = [Customers].CustomerID

WHERE [AStreetAddress] IN (SELECT [AStreetAddress] FROM [Addresses] GROUP BY [AStreetAddress] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate addresses?  First, the customer table seems very irrelevant to this question.  Second, you don't need `left join`.  If addresses are duplicated, then there are matches between the table.  Third, you have two ways to get duplicates:  the address id could be duplicated or the address itself.

If you want the jobs with duplicate addresses, I would expect a query like this:

```
SELECT j.JobId, a.AStreetAddress
FROM [Jobs] j JOIN
     [Addresses] a
     ON j.JobAddressID = a.AddressID  
GROUP BY j.JobId, a.AStreetAddress
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```